# How to remove icon border from Gtk.HeaderBar()

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I have a little app with a Gtk.HeaderBar() defined. There some icons inside but with a border. How can I remove the border.

Ìt looks like this:

[image: header]

```py
        header_bar = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        header_bar.set_show_close_button(True)
        header_bar.props.title = "Invoicy"
        self.set_titlebar(header_bar)

        newbutton = Gtk.Button()
        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(Gio.ThemedIcon(name="document-new"), Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR)
        newbutton.add(image)
        header_bar.pack_start(newbutton)
```